# "Joined subclass strategy" - what is the "object identifier"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In the [Hibernate docs, § 5.1.6.2 - Joined subclass strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass) it states:

> Each subclass must, however, declare a table column holding the object identifier.

The example it gives is as follows:

```java
@Entity @Table(name="CATS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Cat implements Serializable { 
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="cat-uuid") 
    @GenericGenerator(name="cat-uuid", strategy="uuid")
    String getId() { return id; }

    ...
}

@Entity @Table(name="DOMESTIC_CATS")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CAT")
public class DomesticCat extends Cat { 
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

I am guessing that `name` is not the object identifier, so what in the `DomesticCat` class is the "*table column"* that holds the "*Object identifier*"? What would I usually have to do to add this particular required column to my subtypes?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably referring to the "id" field (not shown, but implied by the getId() method).  This field is the unique identifier for the row in the "CATS" table containing the information you are looking for.  It looks like it is setting the Type of id as String and is expecting a UUID.  The sub-types will inherit this field due to their extension of the main class.

Comment: Is that definitely the case? In the TPT (joined-subclass) strategy inherited properties are not stored in the table for the subtype - so are `@Id` columns exceptions to that rule? The only other thing I could think of was that `id` is not inherited and it is the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation that defines it?

Comment: Oh no.  I was thinking of the field in java.  You will want the sub classes to Override the getId() method to put the Hibernate annotations in each sub class on said method.  You will have to do this on any other inherited fields to have the hibernate mapped correctly to the database tables.

Comment: I understood your answer to mean the Java field but there is no code in the example that overrides anything in `DomesticCat`. I also know that in TPT inherited properties (fields/methods depending on Access type) are not persisted in the type's table. So my question is still: what in the `DomesticCat` class is the "*table column"* that holds the "*Object identifier*"? What would I usually have to do to add this particular required column to my subtypes? Are you saying I have to override each field, including `id`? And from your comment, should I override `id` or `getId` or, indeed, neither?

Comment: I believe you want to override the getId() method to put the hibernate annotations on it.